# How connect isql to Sybase Login failed

Tags: linux, odbc, sybase, opensuse

It is simple task take me a lot of time.
I have test Sap system on Open Suse with sybase.
I need to connect by isql to database.

```
vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32% /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql_r -SNPL -Usapsso -PXXXXXXXXXXX -X
CS-LIBRARY error:
        comn_cryptolib_load(): user api layer: internal common library error: Failed to load library '%1!'.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: internal Client Library error: There is a tds login error. The installed encryption handler returned a status that was not CS_SUCCEED.

vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32% /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql64 -SNPL -Usybnpl -
PXXXXXXX -X
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'NPL':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32%
```

UPDATED
According documentation, This message is a generic login failure message that does not tell the connecting user whether the failure resulted from a bad user name or a bad password.
https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01672.1572/html/sec_admin/BABEAIIJ.htm.

```
Set sp_audit "login", "all", "all", "fail"
```

But I can not login to set this parametr)))
How to disable all security?
**ASE backupserver/16.0 SP03 PL06/EBF 28334/P/x86_64/SLES 11.1.**

UPDATED2

```
vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32% /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql64 -SNPL -Usapsso -PXXXXX -X
CS-LIBRARY error:
        comn_cryptolib_load(): user api layer: internal common library error: Failed to load library '%1!'.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: internal Client Library error: There is a tds login error. The installed encryption handler returned a status that was not CS_SUCCEED.
vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32% /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql_r -SNPL -Usapsso -Piamisxiezttyl3 -X  
CS-LIBRARY error:
        comn_cryptolib_load(): user api layer: internal common library error: Failed to load library '%1!'.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: internal Client Library error: There is a tds login error. The installed encryption handler returned a status that was not CS_SUCCEED.



vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32% /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql64 -SNPL -Usybnpl -Pmaster passw0rd -X
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'NPL':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32% /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql64 -SNPL -Usybnpl -Pmaster passw0rd -X
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'NPL':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
vhcalnplci OCS-16_0/bin32%
```

```
vhcalnplci:/usr/sap/hostctrl # su sybnpl
vhcalnplci sap/hostctrl% source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
PATH=/sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/jobscheduler/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/install:/sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
PATH=/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/install:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/jobscheduler/bin:/sybasE-16_0/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/install:/sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin: Command d.
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
PATH=/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/jobscheduler/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/jobscheduler/bin:/sybase/NPL/ASE-16_0/bse/NPL/ASE-16_0/install:/sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SAP_JRE7_32=/sybase/NPL/shared/SAPJRE-7_1_060_32BIT: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SAP_JRE7=/sybase/NPL/shared/SAPJRE-7_1_060_64BIT: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SAP_JRE7_64=/sybase/NPL/shared/SAPJRE-7_1_060_64BIT: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYBASE_OCS=OCS-16_0: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYBASE=/sybase/NPL: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYBASE_ASE=ASE-16_0: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYBROOT=/sybase/NPL: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYBASE_JRE_RTDS=/sybase/NPL/shared/SAPJRE-7_1_060_64BIT: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYBASE_WS=WS-16_0: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
SYSY=123: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
vhcalnplci sap/hostctrl% . /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh
/bin/.: Permission denied.
vhcalnplci sap/hostctrl%
```

```
vhcalnplci sap/hostctrl% bash
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:/usr/sap/hostctrl> source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:/usr/sap/hostctrl>  /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql -SNPL -Usybnpl -P'master password' -X
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'NPL':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:/usr/sap/hostctrl>  /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql -SNPL -Usybnpl -P'XXXXX' -XMsg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'NPL':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:/usr/sap/hostctrl>  /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql -SNPL -Usapsa -P'XXXXX' -X
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'NPL':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:/usr/sap/hostctrl>
```

Comment: what Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) are you trying to connect to? where is `isql` located and what version is it (`type -a isql; isql -v`)? (update the question with your answers); assuming this is the `isql` that comes with the ASE/SDK, `isql` does not use odbc; how to use `isql` is going to depend on what `isql` refers to you in your system

Comment: Thank you. Updated.

Comment: your `find` command found 4x different `isql` files; I'm guessing your `PATH` is configured to pick up one of the first 2 (and I'm assuming one/both of those 2 entries is the odbc-based tool you're trying to use); as a Sybase DBA I've always used the `isql` that comes under the `/sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/` directories (neither of which is odbc-based but instead use the interfaces file): `/sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql -S NPL -U <username>` and then you'll be prompted for a password (alternatively add `-P <password>` on the command line); 'fraid I won't be able to help with the odbc-based `isql` ...

Comment: Yes thank you. I can not suppose that command with same name have different functionality. But it is no solve.... Updated Now i have login failed.... Already reset password for sapsso. But it is not help.

Comment: your comment states you reset the password for login `sapsso` but your 2nd `isql` session is using login `sybnpl`; try `isql64 -S NPL -U sapsso -P xxxxx -X`; as for the first error message ... `isql_r` requires Kerberos drivers to be installed ... I'd avoid using `isql_r` unless you actually need to use Kerberos (at which point you'd need to figure out how to insure the Kerberos drivers are in your `$PATH`)

Comment: The same. with isql64 Not  working))) What is bountiful database!  May be is the way to disable all security on test database preconfigured by SAP?

Comment: please update the question with the exact `isql64` call (masking password is fine) and the complete output/error message; as for disabling security ... your only option would be to reset a password and then try to login with the new password

Comment: Is this a standalone ASE dataserver or is this the backend dataserver for a SAP application? (for the latter SAP typically has a laundry list of instructions/KBAs for this type of issue)

Comment: Standalone server on virtual machine. This is All in one server( SAP+ASE database.) Image of openSuse got from website SAP . The system SAP with database installed by installer. Without any post -configuration. This is test system for learning SAP. I don;'t have SAP user to read this article. A lot of notes not available for me.
It is mean no money no support.

Comment: for the 1st failed `sapsso` login attempt I'm wondering if you forgot to `source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh` ?  as for the failed `sybnpl` logins: `-Pmaster passw0rd` is invalid syntax ... if your password really is the two space separated words `master` and `passw0rd` then you need to quote it, eg: `-P 'master passw0rd`; if instead your password is just `passw0rd` then you want `-P passw0rd`

Comment: /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh have a lot of error.

Comment: what shell are you running under (`bash`? `zsh`? `csh`? something else?) and did you execute the script (`/sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh`) or source it (`source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh`)

Comment: Yes. Run it with command (bash SYBASE.sh). No result the same.Thank you

Comment: when you *run* the script environment settings (in `SYBASE.sh`) are executed in a subshell, those variable assignments are lost when the subshell completes/exits; when you source the file the variable assignments are made in the current shell and thus do not disappear after the 'source' has been completed; for `bash` you should run one of the following: `source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh` or `. /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh` (notice the 2nd option starts with a `period` followed by a `space` and then `/sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh`

Comment: When i run like source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh i got a lot of error. Like SYBASE_WS=WS-16_0: Command not found.
export: Command not found. Suse don't know about export command. The second give pernission denied. Thank you

Comment: when you receive the `export` and permissions errors ... it doesn't look like you're actually running under `bash`; but in your attempts to run `isql` I notice that you ***are*** initiating a `bash` session ***and*** the `source` command runs without issues; so, everything up to that point is working as expected ... errors when running under who-knows-what shell vs no issues when running under `bash`; as for the continuing `isql` errors ... you could try removing the `-X` otherwise it looks like you (still) have issues with providing the wrong password

Comment: I am stupid Users. You are right! It is work. I am not correct run sybase.sh. Thank you a lot for help and time!!!

Comment: sybnpl@vhcalnplci:~> bash
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:~> source /sybase/NPL/SYBASE.sh
sybnpl@vhcalnplci:~> /sybase/NPL/OCS-16_0/bin/isql -SNPL -Usapsa -P'XXXX' -X
1>

Comment: FINALLY! `1> ` is a welcome sight :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!